# Reverse Tunnel is not working

Tags: networking, ssh

Let me explain the configuration. There are three machines (1) my laptop (2) my PC behind the NAT (3) my aws instance with public address. I'm trying to access (2) from (1).

I did this:

```
pc$ ssh -R 2222:localhost:20 aws_user@aws_ip
```

Now I can do the following.

```
laptop$ ssh aws_user@aws_ip
aws$ ssh -p2222 pc_user@localhost
```

That's perfect. However I cannot ssh from my laptop to the PC through my bridge machine (aws). Like this.

```
laptop$ ssh -2531 pc_user@aws_ip
ssh: connect to host aws_ip port 2222: Connection refused
```

netstat -a spills the following:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:2222          *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:48164         localhost:2222          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:2222          localhost:48164         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:2222      [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

And all the ports are open on the aws machine. The following failed as well.

```
ssh -R 2222:*:22
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm answering the question myself. The GatewayPorts needed to be turned on.

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

add GatewayPorts yes

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved me